# How using pact-jvm-provider-junit + http basic auth + Eclipse TPC/IP Monitor?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, basic-authentication, pact

I want to do something like that:

```
private static final String protocol = "http";

// host verification via http basic auth, http://username:passwort@url ...
private static final String host = "http://username:password@myservice.com";
private static final int port = 80;

private static final String path = "/";

@TestTarget
public final Target target = new HttpTarget(protocol, host, port, path);
```

The problem is:
I want to analyse my connection via TCP/IP monitor and it seems it does not give a chance to use http basic auth.
How can I forward the connection through TCP/IP monitor using http basic auth?

Can I set the necessary parameters per headers? Maybe something like that:

```
@TargetRequestFilter
public void exampleRequestFilter(HttpRequest request) {
    request.addHeader("Authorization", "OAUTH hdsagasjhgdjashgdah...");
}
```

Or are there other options how I can use http basic auth + TCP/IP Monitor?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out I can use http base authentication when I encode it via base64.
The solution should look like this:

```
@TargetRequestFilter
public void exampleRequestFilter(HttpRequest request) {
    // Authorization header Base64 encoded...
    String encoded = Base64.getEncoder()
            .encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With Junit 5 this is done differently as [here](https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/jvm/provider/junit5#modifying-the-requests-before-they-are-sent):

```java
    @TestTemplate
    @ExtendWith(PactVerificationInvocationContextProvider.class)
    void testTemplate(PactVerificationContext context, HttpRequest request) {
      // This will add a header to the request
      request.addHeader("X-Auth-Token", "1234");
      context.verifyInteraction();
    }
```